# Want to store state in array in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Hey guys I have a state I want to store it in array how I can do this? And I want to pass it as props in another component is that possible to pass a props in array?

Or do I have to store this state in array where I am passing it to?

Please tell me.

This is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Join extends Component {
constructor(props)
{
super(props)
this.state={
  Rid:'',
  Rname:'',
  Rgender:''
}
this.onChange=this.onChange.bind(this);
this.register=this.register.bind(this);

}
onChange(e)
{
this.setState({[e.target.name]:e.target.value});
console.log(this.state);
}
register(e)
{
e.preventDefault();
this.props.join(this.state.Rid,this.state.Rname,this.state.Rgender);

console.log('ready to go');
}
 render() {
 return (
    <div className="login">

   <form  >
   <img src={require("../images/logo.png")} style=
   {{maxWidth:'80vh',maxHeight:'100vh'}}alt={''}/> 


   <div>
       <label>Your ID:</label>
       <input type="text" name="Rid" onChange=
     {this.onChange}placeholder="Enter your ID"/>

   </div>
   <br/>
   <div>
       <label>Your Name:</label>
       <input type="text" name="Rname"onChange={this.onChange} 
       placeholder="Enter your Name"/>
   </div>
```

```
<label>Your Gender:</label>
<label>Female:</label>
<input type="radio" name="Rgender" value="Female" onChange=
   {this.onChange}/> 

       <label>Male:</label>
       <input type="radio" name="Rgender" value="Male" onChange={this.onChange}/> 

 </div>
 <button type="button" className="btn btn-info" onClick={this.register}>Register</button> 


  </form>

  </div>
```

I am passing it into another component. I want to store it in array.

Comment: Show us the whole component and how are you passing the data to the another component.

Comment: where i show u whole component ??

Comment: in comment session or i edit my question ??

Comment: Edit your question please

Comment: edit..now check it.. its working properly but i want to store my data in array and send it as array if possible and also store data in array into other component where i m pasing it

Comment: you can add an empty arrayin state and at time of register push your join data into that array

Comment: @Damien  give me the soluion

Comment: Anil i know that but i dont know the syntax can u give me the syntax

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Array, put data IN and pass data to another Component:

```
let newArray = [];
newArray.push(this.state);

<OtherComponent data={newArray} />
```

Comment: where u decalre the array ?? it is not in the state

Comment: you declare it in the function that calls your component